# Is there a word for judging thoughtfully?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Being in the act of, at least. For example:

"After several (insert word here) sips, she declared the drink to be acceptable." (The woman has judged her drink with thought and knowledgeable consideration.)

Please note that when I say *thoughtful*, I do not mean the adjective for showing compassion; my usage of the word would be a synonym to "musing" or "contemplative." I have already researched synonyms for both "thoughtful" and all parts of speech relating to the verb "judge," and none have proven satisfying, nor have I come across a word combining the two terms.

Is there an appropriate term?

Comment: Although the adjective [“discerning”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22discerning+sips%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=discerning) is used much more often with the part of the body doing the sipping (“After several sips with/(destined for) her discerning lips/mouth/(palate) …,” [here are 4 occasions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22discerning+sips%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22discerning+sip%22&tbm=bks) where it’s used to describe the sip itself in a way that's somewhat similar to what you describe and which you could perhaps consider as another backup to @Stray 's good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrutinize (scrutinizing) - examine or inspect closely and thoroughly.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrutinize

Comment: I mean, perlustrate could be a backup, but I don't believe the usage lines up as clearly with what you want.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine using this word. To me it means "look at closely", "inspect closely and thoroughly", as you say. So I might *scrutinize* a drink sitting on the table or bar, or *scrutinize* my meal before starting to eat.  Does *scrutinizing sip* really work?

Comment: "After several scrutinizing sips, the sommelier declared the drink to be unacceptable."

Comment: That sounds pretty good, but is it merely an assertion on your part?

Answer (score 0):

"*After several **reflective** sips, she declared the drink to be acceptable.*"

*Reflective* - That proceeds from or is the result of careful thinking, typically influenced by recollection of one's past experiences; considered, measured (OED).

Answer (score 0):

The OP's example:

> "After several ***discriminating*** sips, she declared the drink to be
>   acceptable." (The woman has judged her drink with thought and
>   knowledgeable consideration.)

From Merriam-Webster:

> Blockquote
>
> [*discriminating*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discriminating):
>   liking only things that are of good quality : able to recognize the
>   difference between things that are of good quality and those that are
>   not